# kernel dynamic memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, linux-kernel

For the last month or two, I have been experiencing what I think is a kernel memory leak related to supposedly cached kernel dynamic memory. My system runs an up-to-date Debian/unstable installation on a GL752VW. Roughly twice per day the `Cache` amount of `kernel dynamic memory` reported by `smem -k -t -w` climbs to the limit of my memory (plus swap if I enable it), then grinds to a halt as the OOM desperately tries to kill off processes (but often fails to do so). As I understand it, dropping kernel caches should free up this memory, but as can be seen below, almost none of it gets freed up.

```
brett@debian:~$ uname -a; smem -k -t -u; smem -w -k -t; sync; sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"; smem -k -t -w
Linux debian 4.15.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.15.11-1 (2018-03-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
User     Count     Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
brett       41        0   611.2M   704.1M     1.3G 
---------------------------------------------------
            41        0   611.2M   704.1M     1.3G 
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory          5.6G       5.4G     209.7M 
userspace memory             837.6M     383.3M     454.3M 
free memory                    9.2G       9.2G          0 
----------------------------------------------------------
                              15.6G      14.9G     664.0M 
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory          5.5G       5.3G     209.8M 
userspace memory             837.2M     383.0M     454.2M 
free memory                    9.2G       9.2G          0 
----------------------------------------------------------
                              15.6G      14.9G     663.9M
```

Can anyone confirm whether this is indeed a kernel memory leak and give advice on how to debug/report it as the bi-daily reboots (or hard resets if I don't catch it in time) are getting annoying?

Comment: If you suspect a kernel memory leak and it is OK to rebuild the kernel, you can try the in-kernel memory leak detector, [kmemleak](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/dev-tools/kmemleak.rst). It is not guaranteed that it finds all kernel memory leaks and its reports may be quite noisy sometimes, but it is still very helpful in many cases.

Comment: OK, I'll try that, thanks. For reference if anyone else needs to do this, I'm following [the Debian kernel handbook](https://kernel-handbook.debian.net/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-building) to recompile my kernel and the only changes are `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_EARLY_LOG_SIZE=2000` and `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS` is removed from `.config`.

Comment: Well, I tried doing the above and found a few potential minor memory leaks of <100bytes each, but nothing major. I tried enabling a few more of the options in Memory Debugging section in case they are related, but before I could really test it, the hard disk for my `/home` partition crashed, so I'm waiting for a replacement before going any further.

Comment: Well, I encountered a situation once when a small (10-100 bytes) kernel memory leak in the code that was executed a lot brought the system down eventually. It took several hours of testing but still. If you are not familiar with kernel debugging (yet), you can at least search the Web for similar problems by the names of involved kernel functions, etc. It might also be helpful to edit your question and add the info about the suspected leaks here - there are kernel experts out there that could help analyze them.

Comment: Well, I have my new hard disk installed now, but in the meantime the Debian kernel has updated to 4.16.0-1-amd64 and the above behaviour is no longer apparent. Dropping caches results in just a few hundred MB of cached kernel dynamic memory, which I can live with. Thanks for your help @Eugene.